# CompletableFuture join() call hangs main thread. Individual futures never get completed

Tags: java, completable-future

I am writing a function that creates multiple (7) CompletableFutures. Each of these futures basically does two things :

1. using supplyAsync(), fetch data from some DB
2. using thenAccept(), write this data to a CSV file

When all the 7 futures have finished the job, I want to continue with further code execution. So, I am using allOf() and then calling a join() on the Void CompletableFuture returned by allOf().

The problem is, even after all futures have executed (I can see the CSVs getting generated), the join() call remains stuck and further code execution is blocked forever.

I have tried the following things :

1. Waiting on each future one by one calling a join() after each future. This works but, at the cost of concurrency. I don't want to do this.
2. Tried using get() with a TIMEOUT instead of join(). But, this always ends up throwing an exception (as get always times out) which is undesirable.
3. Saw this JDK bug : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8200347 . Not sure if this is a similar issue.
4. Tried running without a join() or get() which will not hold the thread execution and again is not desirable.

The main function which creates all futures.

```java
public CustomResponse process() {
        CustomResponse msgResponse = new CustomResponse();
        try {
            // 1. DbCall 1
            CompletableFuture<Void> f1 = dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV1();

            // 2. DbCall 2
            CompletableFuture<Void> f2 = dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV2();


            // 3. DbCall 3
            CompletableFuture<Void> f3 = dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV3();


            // 4. DbCall 4
            CompletableFuture<Void> f4 = dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV4();


            // 5. DbCall 5
            CompletableFuture<Void> f5 = dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV5();


            // 6. DbCall 6
            CompletableFuture<Void> f6 = dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV6();


            // 7. DbCall 7
            CompletableFuture<Void> f7 = dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV7();


            CompletableFuture<Void>[] fAll = new CompletableFuture[] {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7};


            CompletableFuture.allOf(fAll).join();
            msgResponse.setProcessed(true);
            msgResponse.setMessageStatus("message");
        } catch (Exception e) {
    msgResponse.setMessageStatus(ERROR);
            msgResponse.setErrorMessage("error");
        }
        return msgResponse;
    }
```

Each of the fetchAndUploadCSV() functions looks like this :

```java
public CompletableFuture<Void> fetchAndUploadCSV1() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                return someService().getAllData1();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).thenAccept(results -> {
            try {
                if (results.size() > 0) {
                    csvWriter.uploadAsCsv(results);
                }
                else {
                    log.info(" No data found..");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is what `csvWriter.uploadAsCsv(results)` looks like -

```java
public <T> void uploadAsCsv(List<T> objectList) throws Exception {
        long objListSize = ((objectList==null) ? 0 : objectList.size());
        log.info("Action=Start, objectListSize=" + objListSize);
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = getCsvAsInputStream(objectList);
        Info fileInfo = someClient.uploadFile(inputStream);
        log.info("Action=Done, FileInfo=" + ((fileInfo==null ? null : fileInfo.getID())));
    }
```

I am using OpenCSV here to convert the data to CSV stream. And I can always see the last log line.

Expected Results :
All data fetched, CSVs generated and CustomResponse should return as processed with no error message.

Actual Results :
All data fetched, CSVs generated and main thread hung.

Comment: What Java version are you running this on? Have you tried with the most recent version of Java 8, or Java 10+, as those were indicated to work in the linked bug?

Comment: I am running Java 8 (u201-b09). Latest Java 8 is u211. I will try that. Haven't tried JDK 10. I won't be able to upgrade JDK in deployment anyway.

Comment: Well the vague status of the bug could suggest it's related. If you can reliably reproduce it, maybe file a new ticket.

Comment: Yes, I have been trying to reproduce it without all the business logic and DB calls. Adding waits and sleeps. Unsuccessful so far.

Comment: The use of CompletableFuture seems to be correct to me. When I tested it everything seemed to work. Are you shure that `csvWriter.uploadAsCsv(results);` works correctly and is not blocking? Maybe there is a problem that occures after the files are created that blocks the execution.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure that `csvWriter.uploadAsCsv(results);` is not blocking. I am adding that code to the question as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP indicated in a comment of the answer that “One of the futures was running an unoptimized DB query and fetching a lot of unnecessary data. Apparently, it was taking a lot of time to fetch and though the rest of the futures completed quickly, this one future made it look like it was blocked.”. Basically the problem cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` on each created `CompletableFuture` without sacrificing concurrency:

```
public CustomResponse process() {
    CustomResponse msgResponse = new CustomResponse();

    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = Arrays.asList(dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV1(),
            dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV2(),
            dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV3(),
            dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV4(),
            dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV5(),
            dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV6(),
            dataHelper.fetchAndUploadCSV7());

    return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[0]))
            .thenApply(v -> {
                msgResponse.setProcessed(true);
                msgResponse.setMessageStatus("message");
                return msgResponse;
            })
            .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                msgResponse.setMessageStatus("ERROR");
                msgResponse.setErrorMessage("error");
                return msgResponse;
            }).join();
}
```

[`allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) returns a new `CompletableFuture` that is completed when all of the given CompletableFutures complete. So, when `join` is invoked in `thenApply`, it returns immediately. In essence, joining is happening to already completed futures. This way blocking is eliminated. Also, to handle possible exceptions, `exceptionally` should be invoked.

Comment: This works but, not exactly how I want it to. What I want is to execute the setProcessed(true) and other statements after that only when all futures are done. Chaining allOf() with thenAccept() removes that behavior. It might even lead to main thread exiting before one or more futures can complete.

Comment: Indeed, described behavior will happen. Updated the answer to use `thenApply` and  additional `join` at the end - this should achieve the behavior you want.

Comment: Got it working. One of the futures was running an unoptimized DB query and fetching a lot of unnecessary data. Apparently, it was taking a lot of time to fetch and though the rest of the futures completed quickly, this one future made it look like it was blocked. For some reason, there was no connection timeout as well.

Comment: Evidently, we need to be very careful while using join() and allOf(). One unoptimized call can block the whole execution flow.

Comment: The above answer is a good alternative to using allOf(). Accepting this, hence.

Comment: The `futures.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);` is unnecessary since, at that point, we already know all futures are already successfully completed, and the returned value is ignored.

Comment: @DidierL Agree, since value returned by individual `CompletableFuture` is just `Void`, that is ignored. In general, when the result is not `Void`, it's useful to `join` and gather/process individual results.